# Events not binding on ajax loaded content when using $(window).scroll(function()

Tags: jquery, wordpress

When I use scroll function in jQuery, the ajax loaded content not having any events.

Basically I am working on an infinite scroll option for my WordPress blog. So I came up with this function.

**Edit** Scroll function and dynamic loading is working fine. But I have a javascript function that add some id to urls of the post. That is not working with dynamically generated posts.

Please help me in this situation.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
    var page = 2;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var target = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {});
    });
});
```

Below is the code that adds a unique affiliate id to all the post urls. Once page loaded it will append unique id to all the post url

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.geni.us/snippet.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var tsid =XXXXX;
        Genius.amazon.convertLinks(tsid, true, "http://buy.geni.us"); });
</script>
```

Comment: @JacobGoh Edited the question.. Scroll is working fine

Comment: `But I have a javascript function that add some id to urls of the post. That is not working with dynamically generated posts.` The function that `add some id to urls of the post` would need to be applied to the generated post AFTER they are generated.

Comment: @JacobGoh I am using Wordpress, these functions  are from some other third party plugins. I don't think so it is practical to write all these functions after generate the ajax response.

Comment: Then it can't be done. Apparently, the function won't be able to add id to an element that will only exist in the future. Just my 2 cents

Comment: If this isn't the code that isn't working why did you post it? It's very likely that your binding of the id to the post is wrong. Please post the code that adds the id instead.

Comment: @JacobGoh But what about .on function, is there anything I can do with that?

Comment: I edited my comment, please post the code that adds the id

Comment: I think you are not knowing that how the wordpress ajax is called? Am i Right ?

Comment: @RickCalder Added the code generates ID, its thirdparty code

Comment: @Aki Wordpress ajax load post is working like a charm

Comment: so you gotta find a way to apply `Genius.amazon.convertLinks` to the newly generated elements without affecting the previously generated elements

Comment: I was wondering there is no way to keep alive the events in Jquery?

Comment: In jQuery yes there is using on, but you have to do it slightly different than normal so it works on dynamic elements https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-bind-click-event-to-dynamically-added-elements-in-jquery.php